# Canonical basis in $l^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

For an exercise, I need to show that the canonical basis is **not** a valid basis in $l^{\infty}$. Concretely, the exercise states :

Consider the Banach space $l^{\infty}$ of sequences $x = \{x_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb{C}$ with the usual norm $\left\| x \right\|_{\infty} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n| < \infty$. Then, we define the sequence $\{e_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty}$ as

$e_m := \{0, ..., 1, 0, ...\}$ , $m \in \mathbb{N}$

i.e. with 1 at the $m$-th position and zeros everywhere else. Show that the system $\{e_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not a basis for $l^{\infty}$.

**My thoughts so far**, please correct me if I am wrong!

1. We need to show that every $x \in l^{\infty}$ can be written as $x = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n(x) e_n$
2. For the dense subset of all those sequences which have only finitely many non-zero entries, $l_c^{\infty} \subset l^{\infty}$, we have that $c_n(x) = x_n$. Then, the expression $x = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n(x) e_n$ is unique.
3. We now need to show that for above choice of $c_n$ and for every $x \in l^{\infty}$ we have that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left\| x -  \sum_{n = 1}^{N} c_n(x) e_n \right\|_{l^{\infty}} = 0$
4. With the chosen $c_n(x) = x_n$ we have that $x - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} c_n(x) e_n = \{0, ..., 0, x_{N+1}, x_{N+2}, ...\}$
5. With $x \in l^{\infty}$ and $\left\| x \right\|_{\infty} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n| < \infty$, we have that $\left\| x - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} c_n(x) e_n \right\|_{l^{\infty}} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} |x_n|$
6. This however is not a Cauchy sequence, hence there is no convergence on this side s.t. $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left\| x -  \sum_{n = 1}^{N} c_n(x) e_n \right\|_{l^{\infty}} = 0$ does not hold.

I am **not sure** whether my conclusion in 6) is right and suffices for this proof. However, I suppose that you can prove this in a much more compact way (and if so, how?).

Help is much appreciated :-)

**Edit :**

The easiest way to solve the problem is to show that $l^{\infty}$ is non-separable since the existence of a Schauder basis as defined in above problem implies that the underlying (sequence) space is separable. I refer to this post to show the non-separability : [Why is $L^{\infty}$ not separable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97648/why-is-l-infty-not-separable)

Thanks @AlvinL and the others!

Comment: Hamel basis or Schauder basis?

Comment: Schauder-basis  :-)

Comment: Existence of Schauder basis implies separable, whereas $\ell _\infty$ is...?

Comment: Ah, okay I think we have not yet discussed separability in this context. Do you have a reference to a proof for $l_{\infty}$ being non-separable?

Comment: $c_n(x) = x_n$ stays the same throughout my proof, i leave it to be $x_n$ :-)

Comment: Your assertion 2. (that the set points with finite support is dense) is wrong.

Comment: It looks like you take any $x\in \ell ^\infty$ and then $c_n(x)$ is the $n$-th coordinate of $x$.  Why do you need to mention  $\ell _c^\infty$ for that? I don't think that's dense, either.

Comment: I followed the explanation of a similar problem for the $l^1$ space and deemed it not necessary but maybe useful. But you are right, it does not matter in this case.

Comment: You shouldn't write a $0$ at the end of $e_m := \{0, ..., 1, 0, ..., 0\}$. It's an infinite sequence, there's not a "last" entry.

Comment: Alright, edited $e_m$. Okay, i understand the concerns. So what do you guys recommend? Is there a much much simpler way? As I said, I followed mostly a solution to a similar problem but was not sure about it either, hence my post! :-)

Comment: Well, try the constant sequence $x_n = 1$, for example. Do you have norm-convergence?

Comment: In $(5)$ there should be $\sup_{n\ge N+1}|x_n|$ on RHS.

Comment: I am confused now. I also see the mistake in my argumentation in 2. 

However, I cannot seem to find a reasonable conclusion here. Is there a better way to prove the statement, i.e. with non-separability? Can someone show or give a reference?

Comment: @aladin I suggested a specific example. Convince yourself the constant sequence can't be represented by the $e_n$ in the required manner.

Comment: @AlvinL Thanks for your comments, I have overlooked them somehow. Thank you very much for the hint to non-separability in your comment above. I think I can prove the statement easily now using non-separability. 

However, for the constant sequence, I do not see why it wouldnt converge in the norm since $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left\| x - \sum_{n = 1}^N x_n \cdot e_n \right\| = 0$ as the sum expression perfectly replicates $x = \{x_n\}$ right? Or where am I wrong? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\sum _{n=1}^N e_n$ is eventually zero for any $N$. Thus, for the constant sequence $x:=(1,1,\ldots)$, $$ \left\| x - \sum _{n=1}^N e_n\right\|_\infty = 1 $$
for every $N\in\mathbb N$. What do we conclude?

The above also disproves the claim of $c_{00}$ being a dense subset of $\ell_\infty$.

---

Alternatively, [existence of Schauder basis implies separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297851/how-to-prove-that-if-a-normed-space-has-schauder-basis-then-it-is-separable-wh). But [$\ell_\infty$ is not separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660418/why-is-l-infty-not-separable).

Comment: Thanks very much! :-)