# Finite rank operators are dense in compact operators on $L^p(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $1\le p \le \infty$ and let $(X,\Omega, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space.If $A\in \mathscr{B_0}(L^P(\mu))$, show that there is a sequence $\{A_n\}$ of finite rank operators such that $||A_n-A||\rightarrow 0$.

I know I need to use [(a useful result)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923634/show-that-every-compact-operator-on-banach-space-is-a-norm-limit-of-finite-rank). But I do not know how to construct those finite rank operators in [(a useful result)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923634/show-that-every-compact-operator-on-banach-space-is-a-norm-limit-of-finite-rank).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288992/there-are-compact-operators-that-are-not-norm-limits-of-finite-rank-operators

Comment: what is your definition of a compact operator ? and the best approximation of rank $N$ (in the sense of operator norm of the residual) is constructed by taking the $N$ greatest singular values/vectors

Comment: @Math1000.Thank you. Is there an answer to this question? I can not find it. could you explain more clear?

Comment: @user1952009.Compact operators are bounded linear operators that the closure of its image of the closed unit ball is compact,i.e.closure of ${T(Ball L^p(\mu))}$ is compact.   could you expain your seond sentence more clear?